# background image, but with opacity css

Tags: html, css, background-image, opacity, scaling

I have an issue with my background not covering the whole site from top to bottom. I know what causes the problem, but as to fixing it I am unsure. My CSS looks like this:

```
#background-img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://images2.alphacoders.com/778/77840.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    width: 61.8%;
    margin-left: 19.1%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : .3;
}
```

The problem seems to happen where the at the point where I add height. But I am not allowed not to have it there as there wont be anything to have a background for. The problem initially is that I need opacity on the image, so I can't just make it cover the wrapper either, as that will give the whole site opacity, not just the background.

Comment: How about a jsfiddle (or something) illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever should read this post. I found a solution. I just moved the whole background-image div to the top of the very wrapper div, and made the position fixed, instead.